# Using scrapy to save files on a web page by extension type

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I am very new to Python and I am trying to use scrapy to download and save the pdf files in this website: 
http://www.legco.gov.hk/general/chinese/counmtg/yr04-08/mtg_0708.htm#hansard

The following is my code:

```
from scrapy.contrib.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.contrib.linkextractors.sgml import SgmlLinkExtractor
from scrapy.spider import BaseSpider
from scrapy.selector import HtmlXPathSelector


class legco(BaseSpider):
  name = "legco"
  allowed_domains = ["http://www.legco.gov.hk/"]
  start_urls = ["http://www.legco.gov.hk/general/chinese/counmtg/yr04-08/mtg_0708.htm#hansard"]
  rules =(
    Rule(SgmlLinkExtractor(allow=r"\.pdf"), callback="save_pdf")
          )

def parse_listing(self, response):
    hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
    pdf_urls=hxs.select("a/@href").extract()
    for url in pdf_urls:
        yield Request(url, callback=self.save_pdf)

def save_pdf(self, response):
    path = self.get_path(response.url)
    with open(path, "wb") as f:
        f.write(response.body)
```

Basically I tried to restrict the search to just links with ".pdf" and then select by "a/@hfref".

From the output, I see this error:

> 2015-03-09 11:00:22-0700 [legco] ERROR: Spider error processing http://www.legco.gov.hk/general/chinese/counmtg/yr04-08/mtg_0708.htm#hansard>

Can anyone advise how can I fix my code? Thanks a lot!

Comment: I edited your title slightly since the fact that the files you're trying to scrape are PDFs really has nothing to do with your problem (beyond that you're trying to scrape all files with a particular extension).

Comment: You should also fix up the indentation in your code sample, though it's clear enough from context what's going on.  Unless of course your actual code is also mis-indented in which case there's your problem.  After the error message does the log show a traceback?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First of all, *you need to use a `CrawlSpider`* if you want the `rules` to work. Also, the `rules` should be defined as an iterable, usually it is a tuple (there was a missing comma).

Anyway, instead of taking this approach, I would use a normal `BaseSpider`, loop over the links and check the `href` to end with `.pdf`, then, in the callback, save a pdf to a file:

```
import urlparse

from scrapy.http import Request
from scrapy.spider import BaseSpider


class legco(BaseSpider):
    name = "legco"

    allowed_domains = ["www.legco.gov.hk"]
    start_urls = ["http://www.legco.gov.hk/general/chinese/counmtg/yr04-08/mtg_0708.htm#hansard"]

    def parse(self, response):
        base_url = 'http://www.legco.gov.hk/general/chinese/counmtg/yr04-08/'
        for a in response.xpath('//a[@href]/@href'):
            link = a.extract()
            if link.endswith('.pdf'):
                link = urlparse.urljoin(base_url, link)
                yield Request(link, callback=self.save_pdf)

    def save_pdf(self, response):
        path = response.url.split('/')[-1]
        with open(path, 'wb') as f:
            f.write(response.body)
```

(worked for me)